# Что уместнее использовать: «больше» или «более»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, грамматика, лексическая-сочетаемость, сравнение

Иногда даже маленькой вещи в жизни больше/более чем достаточно…

Что уместнее употребить тут: «больше» или «более»?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, насколько я знаю, есть выражение именно *бол**е**е чем достаточно.*